# django view filter ManyToMany field to guard view

Tags: django, orm

I have a tag model, with ManyToMany field "parents" to tag model, to itself. There is also "allowed_users" field.

I need to guard a view in such a way, that the user won't see any tags in parents field, to which he is not allowed.

I try to modify queryset, removing the corresponding tags from parents. But when I change the instance, `tag_instance.parents.set(my_new_list)` it gets saved automatically so I'm altering the database and changing the real value of the instance.

So the general question is "how to guard my view in such a way, that object's ManyToMany field is filtered by custom logic".

Another question is "how to set manytomany field without altering database", as this would be a solution to the former one.

yes I use DRF

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Prefetch object to filter related table when SQL queries are executed.
For instance:

```
Tag.objects.preftech_related(Prefetch("parents", queryset=Tag.objects.filter(allowed_users=current_user).distinct()))
```

This will prefetch "parents" (meaning no additionnal sql query will run when accessing `my_tag.parent.all()`) and filter parents to keep only those with the current user in allowed_user

Note: `Tag.objects.filter(allowed_users=current_user)` will duplicate tag entries for each user in allowed_user, ence the `.distinct()` to keep one of each